# $G$ is finite group with $N$ normal in $G$, not contained in $Z(G)$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $N$ be a proper normal subgroup of $G$. If $N$ is not contained in in the center $Z(G)$, then prove that there exists a proper subgroup $H$ of $G$, such that $|H|>\sqrt{|G|}$.

Attempt: Since $N\not\subset Z(G)$, we get $x\in N-Z(G)$. Since $x\notin Z(G)$, we get $C(x)=\{g\in G:gx=xg\}$, the centralizer subgroup of $x$ is proper. Now $|G|/|C(x)|=[G:C(x)]=|[x]|$, where $[x]$ is the conjugacy class of $g$. Now if we can show that $|[x]|<|C(x)|$, then we will be done. Also note that $x\in N$ implies that $[x]=\{gxg^{-1}:g\in G\}\subset N$ thus we also have $|[x]|\leq|N|$. Now if we can prove that $|N|<|C(x)|$ then we'll be done. If possible let $|N|\geq |C(x)|$.

But I'm stuck after that. Please let me know if i can proceed after that, or you may give me a hint for another process.

Comment: Can you tell what $\sqrt G$ means?

Comment: @VikrantDesai: That's $\sqrt{|G|}$, square root of the order of $G$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You would be done if you knew that $N$ was "small" enough.  How small do you need to know $N$ is, exactly, in order to finish your proof?  If $N$ is large instead of small, then can you see a different way you can  prove the existence of such an $H$?

A more detailed hint is hidden below:

> If $|N|>\sqrt{|G|}$, then you can just take $H=N$.  If $|N|\leq\sqrt{|G|}$, can you use this to prove $|C(x)|<\sqrt{|G|}$?

Comment: If $|N|\leq\sqrt{|G|}$, then $|C(x)|=|G|/|[x]|>|G|/|N|\geq\sqrt{|G|}$. Note that we have $|G|/|[x]|>|G|/|N|$ because $[x]\subsetneqq N$ as $e_G\notin [x]$

Comment: Yep, looks good!